# Disable "Automatically save changes after each edit"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

Everytime I start an ArMap 10.2.2 session the "Automatically save changes after each edit" is checked (turned on). The way our database works this poses issues. I would like to find a way to have this disabled or turned off when users start an ArcMap session. Has anyone found a way?

[image]

Comment: If Alex Tereshenkov's suggestions don't work, this might not have an easy solution. Looks like this is a bug that is fixed at 10.3.

http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDk4OTkx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution to this is to set the Options for the Editor as required and save the map document. When users will open this .mxd all the settings will be preserved.

Alternatively, you could put the saved map document into the `C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates`. Then this document will appear in the list of available options when starting ArcMap. You would need to copy this map document to all of the users over the network.

[image]

Read more about working with [map templates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002w000000) and [Fundamentals of saving your customizations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00v000000005000000).