# Editing a feature adds it to the "feature exclusion" list

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing

Recently one of our editors found a strange issue with some feature classes in a particular feature dataset. When she moves a vertex and then clicks off the feature, the feature vanishes from the display. It can still be selected, identified, and seen in the attribute table, it's just not visible on the screen.

After some exploration, we noticed that the "invisible" features are getting added to the Feature Exclusion list (on the Layer Properties / Display tab) after they are added. When the "Restore All" button is pushed, the features magically reappear. [There is extremely little information about Feature Exclusion available](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/2442), unfortunately.

It's a relief to know why this is happening, and good that we have a workaround, but ideally we want to not force the editors to open layer properties to push a button each time they edit a polygon. Why are those features getting added to the excluded features list, and how can we prevent that from happening?

---

Possibly related (and discovered at the same time), the "Automatically save changes after each edit" option was checked in the editor. ([This appears to be a 10.2 bug](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141835/disable-automatically-save-changes-after-each-edit), and I am not sure if it's related to the Feature Exclusion behavior or not.)

The dataset is unversioned (since it is also used by a map viewer feature service). Database and ArcMap are both 10.2.1.

Comment: If anyone comes here by luck to find out what is the **feature exclusion list** under **Display** tab of a layer and how it gets populated, one reason for that is conversion of features to graphics. Basically if you make a selection and decide to convert them to graphics with **Only draw the converted graphics** option, your selection is added to this exclusion list as explained in http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/converting-between-graphics-and-features-about-con.htm

Comment: Additionally, under Customize>Commands>Selection, there is a command button called **Exclude Unselected Features**, which has the same effect as explained in https://geonet.esri.com/thread/2442